# Can long running queries cause application performance

Tags: database

If a query runs more than 24 hours in my database, will it cause any performance issue to my application? If yes what would be the reason ?

Comment: Well, a query would need a CPU to run, and if it runs continuously for 24 hours, you've 1 less CPU to run other set of queries. Hence there is going to be performance degradation for the application.

Comment: What is you DBMS ?